# Center popups in Qgis2web WebMap

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I am trying to code anything in the HTML coming from Qgis2web to center a popup in the screen when open it without having to scroll aroung the screen to see all info. Ej;

[image]

And I would like to see all info after the click:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that qgis2web Leaflet exports normally do this by default. However, I think the cause of the issue in your case is the presence of images in your popups. I believe that the popup has scrolled into full view before the image has loaded. qgis2web doesn't retrieve the dimensions of popup images, so it doesn't set the height and width of the `<img>`. That means it resizes after the image has loaded, and *after* Leaflet has scrolled the popup (without image) into view. Try temporarily removing the images from the popups to confirm whether that makes the popups scroll into view.

If confirmed, I'm afraid I don't have a solution for this at the moment.